# PR suddenly required approvals from unexpected approvers after rebase in github

Tags: git, github, rebase

There was an issue related to github behaviour and would love to have your ideas

To start with, the structure of our department's repo is as follows:

```
.codeowner
-- main
---- department_a # Owner - engineers_team_a
------- subfolder_1
---------- my_script_1.sql
---------- my_script_2.sql
---- department_b # Owner - engineers_team_b
---- department_c # Owner - engineers_team_c
...
...
---- department_z # Owner - engineers_team_z
```

I initiated a PR to update both my_script_1.sql and my_script_2.sql. Additionally, I added two new lines to the .codeowner file without altering any existing lines.

Subsequent to my PR, there were alterations made to the same scripts within the same PR by another individual. Concurrently, there was a separate PR that also modified the same scripts and was merged before mine. To streamline the commit history and circumvent any merge conflicts, I opted for a git rebase.

Previously, the required approver in github was only engineers_team_a.
When I ran the rebase function, the log showed that there are lots of modified files in other folders.

Afterwards, when I pushed the PR, in the github web page it showed that I have 2 file changed, which is as expected, but suddenly all teams e.g engineers_team_b, engineers_team_c until engineers_team_z became the required approver and I was seemed to be the one who proposed changes for all departments.

Does anyone also experienced this issue before? If yes, do you know any possible reason why?
Thank for the help in advance!